# mouseSensitivity not working for ColumnChart in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to use "mouseSensitivity" property of ColumnChart in flex. 
From the  [example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_04.html)  tutorial I have learnt how this property works. 
But In my program it seems not working. By that what I mean is even though if I give very less value say mouseSensitivity=1 and if I place mouse pointer far away from the data point, even then its attracted to the nearest data point. Which is not desirable in my program.

```
<mx:ColumnChart id="energyChart" mouseSensitivity="1" dataProvider="{energyXml.scenario}" selectionMode="single" chartClick="energyChart_chartClickHandler(event)" >    

 <mx:series>
   <mx:ColumnSeries id="energySeries" />
   <mx:LineSeries id="lineSeries" />
 </mx:series>

</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys...

I got why its going wrong, Initially I gave line series width as '100', so flex taking mouse pointer as in its range even though its not in the "mouseSensitivity" range....

Thanks...